# +200-Punkte-Limit gefallen?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Ich habe gerade festgestellt, dass ich heute 226 Punkte bekommen habe. Ich dachte aber, es gibt ein Limit, dass nur die Vergabe von maximal 200 Punkten an eine Person erlaubt. Zumindest glaube ich mich erinnern zu können, dass das früher mal so war. Hat sich da was geändert? Vielleicht gleichzeitig mit der Layout-Umstellung?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Das Limit betrifft nur Erfahrung durch Upvotes und Edits. Erfahrung durch akzeptierte Antworten und Bounties wird nicht berücksichtigt. [Aus der FAQ](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation):

> Bounty awards, accepted answers, and association bonuses are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

Da heute drei Deiner Antworten akzeptiert wurden, ist alles unter 245 Punkten im Rahmen.